# добавить id каждой записи в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть страница где выведены записи из категории

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=28');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <div class="post">
        <div class = "news_img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class = "clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_query();                
    ?>
```

Как добавить id уникальный каждой записи в блоке .post? можно числовой

Comment: `<?= $post->ID; ?>`

Comment: и куда это вставить?

Comment: все, разобрался

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался

```
<?php
    if ( have_posts() ) :
    query_posts('cat=28');
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
    <div class="post" id="<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="news_img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
        <div class="entry-summary">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <?php 
        endwhile;
        endif;
    wp_reset_query();                
    ?>
```

Comment: Вы там с кавычками напутали

Comment: случайно так вышло.